# errro executing shellcode in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, shellcode

I want to execute shellcode using visual studio 2015 C++ and  windows10 but I got the following error : 
"Exception thrown at 0x0019FF06 in ConsoleApplication4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x004118C3."

Code:

```
char shellcode[] ="\x58\xc3"  
"\x18\x11\x7b\x76"
"\x8b\x00\xc3"  
"\x50\x89\x8e\x54\x00\x00\x00\x5e\xc3" 
"\x5d\xc3" 
"\xff\xe4" 
"\x5b\xc3"
"\x01\x02\x00\x00" 
"\x59\xc3"  
"\x76\x0e\x7e\x76" 
"\x5f\xc3"
"\xc3" 
"\x58\xc3"
"\x90 "
"\x20\x18\x41\x00"; 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
__asm {
        lea eax, shellcode
        call    eax
    }
}
```

Also Can the code shell code be executed on different method ?

Comment: Well apparently your CPU doesn't like it when you try to execute data.

Comment: ^^ You might want to try using `VirtualProtect` to make your data buffer executable. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898.aspx

Comment: UAC if enabled for all apps will prevent this code from running, but that's not the error you're getting.  What do you think your shellcode is going to do, 'cause it won't do what you think it's going to.

Comment: I am using virtualprotect inside shellcode by using the method address , my shellcode used ROPgadgets from kernel32.lib